# Username for logged in JAAS user on JBoss EAP 6.2 and Seam 2.3.1

Tags: jboss7.x, jaas, seam2, jboss-eap-6

After the user logs in with FORM authentication, I need to get the user's username. I'm using a custom login module that extends DatabaseServerLoginModule.

I'm runing JBoss EAP 6.2 (standalone) and Seam 2.3.1.

I've but a breakpoint in my loginmodule, and I can see from the stacktrace (and my browser's dev tools, where I can see the newly created JSESSIONID cookie) that the session has been created. I thought I could manually map JSESSIONIDs to usernames, but I can't see a way to find that. Inside my normal Seam Session scoped stuff, I could use FacesContext / ExternalContext.getSession(), but FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is always null there.

In the stack trace I can see the FormAuthenticator and I thought I could get this stuff from there, but I haven't found a way to use a custom version of that.

I found something that recommended using an org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain annotation along with a javax.annotation.Resource annotated / injected javax.ejb.SessionContext, but the SessionContext (from which I could call getCallerPrincipal) is always null. I guess Seam's idea of a Session and whatever that stuff maps to doesn't play well together.